# map() function increase the dimension in python

Tags: python, numpy

I got a very strange problem about the map function, it will increase a dimension automatically.

```
matrix = range(4)
matrix = numpy.reshape(matrix,(2,2))
vector = numpy.ones((1,2))
newMatrix = map(lambda line: line/vector, matrix)
np.shape(newMatrix) # I got (2,1,2)
```

I am confused, the matrix has the shape(2,2), but why after the map() function, the newMatrix has such a shape (2,1,2)? How can I fix with this problem?

Comment: What behavior do you expect?  What is your lambda function supposed to be doing?

Comment: Oh, I found the "vector" is the problem, because it has a shape (1,2) and not (2,), so "line/vector" has also the shape (1,2). If I change the "vector" to vector[0], the problem will be soluted. But are there some better methods?

Comment: Hi Curt F. , I expect the newMatrix has also the (2,2) shape

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is simply `newMatrix = matrix / vector`. Remember that `numpy` performs element-wise operations. `map` is doing what it is defined to do, i.e. return a list after applying your function to each item in the iterator. So `map` operates on each row of your matrix at a time. You have two rows; thus, your new shape is 2 x 1 x 2.

Comment: Hi TehTechGuy, thanks! But do you know,how can I turn the "vector " to the  shape (2,), without writing "vector[0]" ?

Comment: What operation are you trying to do, exactly? Do you want to divide each row `matrix` by `vector` or are you trying to do something else? If you simply want a 2 x 2 matrix filled with 1s all you have to do is `numpy.ones((2,2))`.

Comment: I want to simply divide each row from matrix by `vector`

Comment: Then use the code I posted in my solution to replace what you have for `newMatrix = ...`. `numpy` uses element-wise operations, which means that it will divide each element in matrix by the corresponding element in vector, so it's the same as doing this: `newMatrix = [[matrix[0][0] / vector[0][0], matrix[0][1] / vector[0][1]], [matrix[1][0] / vector[0][0], matrix[1][1] / vector[0][1]]]`

Answer (score 1):

This example may illustrate what is going on  (I replaced your 'matrix', and 'vector' names with neutral variable names)

```
In [13]: x = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
In [14]: y=np.ones((1,2))

In [15]: list(map(lambda line:line/y, x))
Out[15]: [array([[ 0.,  1.]]), array([[ 2.,  3.]])]
```

Notice the 2 arrays have shape `(1,2)`, which matches that of `y`.  `x[0,:]/y` shows this as well.  Wrap that list in `np.array...`, and you get a `(2,1,2)`.

Notice what happens when I use a 1d array, `z`:

```
In [16]: z=np.ones((2,))

In [17]: list(map(lambda line:line/z, x))
Out[17]: [array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 2.,  3.])]
```

I ran this sample in Python3, where `map` returns a generator.  To get an array from that I have to use

```
np.array(list(map(...)))
```

I don't think I've seen the use of `map` with numpy arrays before.  I'm a little surprised that in Python2 it returns an array, not just a list.  A more common version of your iteration is to wrap a list comprehension in `np.array...`

```
np.array([line/y for line in x])
```

But as noted in the other answer, you don't need iteration for this simple case. `x/y` is sufficient.  How to avoid iteration is a frequent SO question.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed answer! I am very new in python. It is a very good suggestion to avoid iteration, because I used to think the iteration  is beautiful and elegant. Also, now, I understand the different between numpy.array and and numpy.matrix. (originally, I was confused by the numpy.ndarray, numpy.matrix, and list )